# How to add div to top menu item

Tags: menus

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-15"><a href="link.html">XXX</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Where "XXX" I want to put

The reason I want to do it is that I'm coding top menu and I want to display a picture on hover of the link.

It would be like that:

.menu ul li:hover myClass {
display:block;
}

Example of what effect I am trying to accomplish can be see in top menu here http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/37119.html

I've searched all the template files and it seems that this link is generated somewhere in php file in wp-content folder and I can't find it.

---

I've solved the problem.

The solution was that I don't need to edit any stuff in wp-includes.I only needed to add parameters in my template file.

In the beggining I had this code in header:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary') ); ?>
```

So I just added `'link_after' => '<div class="one"></div>',` after `array(` and it worked fine.

Thanks you Bainternet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using  [**`wp_nav_menu`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) you can pass arguments to it which help you style the output, look at:

- `$container`  Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it with. Allowed
  tags are div and nav. Use false for no container e.g. container =>
  false .
- `$container_class` the class that is applied to the container.
- `$container_id` The ID that is applied to the container.
- `$menu_class`  CSS class to use for the containing div element which
  forms the default menu, or the ul element when a custom menu is
  configured in the admin interface.
- `$before` Output text before the  of the link.
- `$after`  Output text after the  of the link.
- `$link_before` Output text before the link text.
- `$link_after` Output text after the link text.
- `$items_wrap` Whatever to wrap the items with an ul, and how to wrap
  them with.

So in you case you can use

```
array( 'link_before' => '<div class="your_class">' , 'link_after' => '</div>');
```

But if you ask me you can probably do what you want with the classes WordPress prints out anyway.

Comment: +1 IMHO the last paragraph of the answer is the most important one :)

Comment: @Bainternet Could you please tell me which part of nav-menu-template to modify.I'be been searchingm but there are 500lines of code, and not the simple one to me at least.

Comment: @Tomas you missed the point, you don't need to modify anything.
edit you question with the code you use to print the menu and i'll show you.

Maugly: +1 for catching that :)

Comment: @Bainternet thanks a lot! Now I got it.I posted my solution in the first post.I'm glad I could do it without editing anything outside my theme :)

Comment: @Tomas Glad it worked for you :)